# Update multiple check boxes with PHP and SQL

Tags: php, sql, input, checkbox, pdo

i am updating multiple input field (text) with the following script:

**Frontend**

```
<!-- User Input -->
<form method="POST">
 <input name="id[]" value="<?=row['id']?>" hidden>    
 <input type="text" name="text[]" value="<?=$row['text']?>>
** some submit button **
</form>
```

**SQL (PDO) Update**

```
<!-- Updating every row  -->
$statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE textbase SET text= rtrim(:text) WHERE id = :id");
      $statement->bindParam(":text", $text, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $statement->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      foreach ($_POST['text'] as $index => $text) {
      $id = $_POST['id'][$index];
      $statement->execute();
    }
```

This works perfectly and w/o any issue. However i have tried to add now by the same way a checkbox for every row (id). I made the following changes for the frontend code:

**Problem script:**

```
    <!-- User Checkbox -->
        <form method="POST">
        
        <!-- Pass the id for the row -->
        <input name="id[]" value="<?=row['id']?>" hidden>  

<?php // Check if the box needs to be checked as standard
if($row['checkbox'] == '1') { $check = "checked"; } else { $check = ""; } ?>
        
        <!-- If box is not checked send value 0 to avoid empty POST -->
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="0" hidden>  
        
        <!-- Checkbox -->
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="1" <?=$check?>>
    
    ** some submit button **
    
    </form>
```

**New SQL PDO Query**

```
 <!-- Updating every row  -->
$statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE textbase SET checkbox= rtrim(:checkbox) WHERE id = :id");
      $statement->bindParam(":checkbox", $checkbox, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $statement->bindParam(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $index => $checkbox) {
      $id = $_POST['id'][$index];
      $statement->execute();
    }
```

I just used the same PHP PDO Update query, just replaced "text" with "checkbox". This seems not to be working and i could not find the reason why. The result is very confusing. For me it looks like there is a problem by allocate the id to the result for each row. Any hint from you guys what i have missed?

Comment: Did you update the `foreach` in your PDO setup to include the right POST field?

Comment: Yes true, thats what i meant with: I just used the same PHP PDO Update query, just replaced "text" with "checkbox". I have observed that everytime i check a box in my list the first itemd gets checked. If i check another box in my list the second item gets checked. Deactivate is impossible. (I added the updated query for better understanding).

Comment: Do you consider the fact that checkboxes that are unchecked wont be present in $_POST? for example if you have 3 checkbox input and you checked 2 of them, after the submit button your $_POST['checkbox'] has 2 member!

Comment: Yes, thats what i avoid with this: <!-- If box is not checked send value 0 to avoid empty POST --> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="0" hidden>

Comment: What your $_POST['checkbox'] looks? can you show us a var_dump or something?

Comment: And maybe another useless fact is your id field is not array ( name="id[]" ) so you cant get it as $_POST['id'][$index]

Comment: @Debuqer missing [] in name="id[]" is a typo here. In my code i have it. Doing the var_dump... sec...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240680/discussion-between-mischa-mustermann-and-debuqer).

Comment: You never actually use the `$check` variable to reflect the checked status for the record

Answer (score 0):

After a few test i noticed that the value of hidden checkbox wont present in $_POST
and the reason is that you missed ***checked*** keyword.
Only checked checkboxes will sent to backend

so you need to do something like this

```html
<!-- User Checkbox -->
        <form method="POST">
        
        <!-- Pass the id for the row -->
        <input name="id[]" value="<?=row['id']?>" hidden>  

<?php // Check if the box needs to be checked as standard
if($row['checkbox'] == '1') { $check = "checked"; } else { $check = ""; } ?>
        
        <!-- If box is not checked send value 0 to avoid empty POST -->
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="0" hidden checked>    <----------
        
        <!-- Checkbox -->
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="1" <?=$check?>>
    
    </form>
```

And now you get both values

I'm not sure how you want to handle the result but to me a better option is to add an index to checkboxes so you can access them more easier and it prevents loosing unchecked values

```html
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[0]" value="0" hidden checked>    
        <!-- Checkbox -->
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[0]" value="1" <?=$check?>>

        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[1]" value="0" hidden checked>    
        <!-- Checkbox -->
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[1]" value="1" <?=$check?>>
```

or maybe the better solution is to let back-end to be worry about unchecked and checked values .

```html
        <!-- Checkbox -->
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[0]" value="1" <?=$check?>>

        <!-- Checkbox -->
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[1]" value="1" <?=$check?>>
```